# How to call a server side java method from HTML using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax

I want to know how to call a java method from HTML (I Use HTML5) using java script. I tried using Applets but this didnt work. I have to take the value of a drop down box in the html file and take it to a java method to process it.

Comment: Applets? WTH. AJAX is the way to go.

Comment: Yes  I do have an application server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is AJAX. It's extremely easy to do with a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

```
$.get('your/servlet').done(function(data) {
    // data is the data returned by the request
});
```

Comment: This is only the client part, which is not enough to answer the question.

Comment: The server-side code just needs to expose the function via an URL. Without knowing anything about his server-side architecture that's part impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Jabsorb implements this: http://code.google.com/p/jabsorb/

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do this with a request to a servlet.  Like ThiefMaster said, Ajax is a good way to go

Here's a quick article to get you started: http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/